# Writing an image's bytes to a text file

Tags: vb.net, text

I need to write an image's byte information to a text file.  For the most part, I've done it, but it seems that by encoding the bytes in UTF8, there is additional informated encoded into the image data, stuff that doesn't belong.  Most notably, 0xEF and 0xBF consecutively.  I can only assume it's because I'm encoding with UTF8.  So then the question becomes, how do I write the image bytes to a text file without an encoder molesting the data?

On the left is the text file, and the right is the image:
[image]
I've done some really elaborate things, and really simple things.

From this:

```
Dim str As String = String.Empty
For Each c In byteArray
    str &= ChrW(c)
Next
```

To this:

```
Dim labelFileStream As FileStream = New FileStream(labelPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
Dim labelStreamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(labelFileStream)
Dim f_convOutBytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(f_imagePath)
Dim totalStreamLength As Int32 = f_convOutBytes.Length
Dim labelOutStream(totalStreamLength - 1) As Byte
f_convOutBytes.CopyTo(labelOutStream, 0)
labelStreamWriter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(labelOutStream))
labelStreamWriter.Close()
labelFileStream.Close()
```

If I set a breakpoint before the streamwriter closing and check the string, it doesn't have all the extra characters in it.

> ChrW(137) & "PNG" & vbCrLf & ChrW(26) & vbLf & vbNullChar & vbNullChar
>   & vbNullChar & vbCr & "IHDR" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ChrW(2) & "Í"
>   & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & "Ë" & ChrW(4) & ChrW(3) &
>   vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & "g§³" & ChrW(134) & vbNullChar
>   & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ChrW(1) & "sRGB" & vbNullChar & "®Î" &
>   ChrW(28) & "é" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ChrW(4) &
>   "gAMA" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & "±" & ChrW(143) & vbVerticalTab &
>   "üa" & ChrW(5) & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & "0PLTE" &
>   vbBack & vbBack & vbBack & ChrW(24) & ChrW(24) & ChrW(24) &
>   "&&&888HHHXXXhhhxxx" & ChrW(136) & ChrW(136) & ChrW(136) & ChrW(152) &
>   ChrW(152) & ChrW(152) & "¨¨¨¸¸¸ÒÒÒØØØèèèøøø!ä0" & ChrW(144) &
>   vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbTab & "pHYs" & vbNullChar &
>   vbNullChar & ChrW(14) & "Ã" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ChrW(14) & "Ã"
>   & ChrW(1) & "Ço¨d" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ")ÄIDATxÚí" & ChrW(157)
>   & "I@SI·Ç" & ChrW(19) & "ðí" & vbTab & "Á½LöV" & vbBack & vbTab &
>   "½l!" & vbFormFeed & "î^ËÜ»'" & ChrW(138) & "Bï" & ChrW(26) & "dòí" &
>   ChrW(26) & ChrW(20) & "Á¥ " & vbFormFeed & "½" & ChrW(148) & ChrW(153)
>   & "oÙ" & ChrW(132) & "!¬Í" & vbNullChar & "®%" & ChrW(16) & "ö" &  ...
>   ... ...

Going further, it seems that certain characters cause this.  Specifically non-ASCII characters.
Incorrect data
[image]
Positions of incorrect data translated by NPP.
[image]
Expected output with the positions that have incorrect data highlighted.
[image]
Side by side comparison
[image]

Comment: I think I've confirmed that it is the UTF encoding.  I have a small program that does what I need automatically.  If I open the file with VSCode and save it, all of a sudden it has the extra chars in it.  Then again, if I open the file with Notepad++ and save it, the file stays as it should.  Arg.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use ASCII.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it doesn't matter what I use.  For whatever reason, once the file is written, it is filled in seemingly random locations with Hex EFBF.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I'm very confused by your question. You seem to be confused by the difference between bytes and strings and are unclear on the meaning and purpose of the string encoding, but since I can't tell for sure what you're asking, I don't know where to begin. Are you having trouble saving, loading, or displaying? How are you getting the bytes for the image? Can you provide a simple example which includes the input data, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: OK, after re-reading your question, it's a little more clear to me what you are trying to do, but I'm still don't understand what you expect the output to be.  What do you mean by a text file?  What do you expect the text to say?  The source data is not text.  It's not intended to be viewed as text, so to say that you want to output it as text doesn't really make any sense.  It's already a series of bytes, in the original file, which can be viewed using any encoding you want.  To change it to a text file, all you need to do is rename it to `.txt`.

Comment: If that's not what you want to do, you need to be clear about what you want.  On one hand, you're saying that you want it to convert it to some other format, but then you're saying that you don't want the other format to be any different than the original.  If you don't want it to be different, why are you converting it?  And, again, what do you mean by converting an image to text?  You want to convert it to columns of hex numbers?  You want to show the ASCII equivalents of all the byte values?  You want to convert it to ASCII art?

Comment: @StevenDoggart I've updated the OP.  Take a look.  It seems once the stream saves the file, it converts non-ascii characters to `ï¿½`.

Comment: Yes, it will be different.  Of course it will be different.  The question is, what do you want it to be and why?  If you don't want it to be different, why are you converting it to a different format?

Comment: @Jaberwocky The random bytes of an image and Unicode are not compatible. There are sequences of bytes which are illegal in Unicode.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Sorry for the slow responses, I was on the phone.   I've added a final image showing the expected output.  That image data is the production of a working "converter tool" that basically does this similar job.

Comment: @StevenDoggart This is for a cluster of printers.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your expected output is identical to your input.  If so, then don't do anything to it.  Just copy the file as is and make no changes.  If they are supposed to be different in some way, please explain how.

Comment: Because I need to append ASCII commands and settings to the beginning and end of the image data.  Am I completely overdoing this?  I added a side by side comparison of the outputs, their app on the left, my app on the right in vscode utf8.

Comment: Appending extra bytes to the beginning doesn't require you to reencode the image data.  Just add the bytes you want to add, then add all the original bytes, as they already are, without converting them in any way.

Comment: @StevenDoggart at the risk of being super annoying, how do you propose I do that?  Wanna throw in a quick answer? :D

Comment: "Because I need to append ASCII commands and settings to the beginning and end of the image data.": Ah, the X of the XY Problem. Please [edit] this into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is, you are taking the image data, pretending like it's text, decoding it into text using a particular encoding, and then writing it out to the output stream using the `StreamWriter`, which re-encodes the "text" back to bytes again, most likely using a different encoding.  Even if you used the same encoding to read and write it, it would be problematic, since not all byte arrays are valid text, so you may lose some data in the conversion (much like translating a sentence from English into Spanish and then back from Spanish into English again). 
 However, when you aren't even using the same encoding both ways, you're definitely not going to get the same result.  Since it's not text, there's no reason to convert it into text at all.  Just leave it as a series of raw bytes and don't alter their values.

To copy the bytes from the original image file to the output stream, without making any modifications to the data, you can do it like this:

```
Using outputStream As New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim imageBytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath)
    outputStream.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
End Using
```

Or, better yet, if you can open the source image file as a stream, you can do it like this:

```
Using outputStream As New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Using inputStream As New FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks!  I already had something similar in the works.  Just working on inserting the ASCII bytes to the beginning and end of the image data now.